# thread Invocation in C# .WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, invoke, invokerequired

there.
I'm using C# .wpf, and I get this some code from C# source, but I can't use it. is there anything that I must change? or do?

```
 // Delegates to enable async calls for setting controls properties
    private delegate void SetTextCallback(System.Windows.Controls.TextBox control, string text);

    // Thread safe updating of control's text property
    private void SetText(System.Windows.Controls.TextBox control, string text)
    {
        if (control.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            Invoke(d, new object[] { control, text });
        }
        else
        {
            control.Text = text;
        }
    }
```

As above code, the error is in `InvokeRequired` and `Invoke`

the purpose is, I have a textbox which is content, will increment for each process.

here's the code for the textbox. `SetText(currentIterationBox.Text = iteration.ToString());`

is there anything wrong with the code?

thank you for any help

EDIT

```
// Delegates to enable async calls for setting controls properties
    private delegate void SetTextCallback(System.Windows.Controls.TextBox control, string text);

    // Thread safe updating of control's text property
    private void SetText(System.Windows.Controls.TextBox control, string text)
    {
        if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            control.Text = text;
        }
        else
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            Dispatcher.Invoke(d, new object[] { control, text });
        }
    }
```

Comment: And exactly what is the error?

Comment: have you get any error or you only assume that you have error in your code?

Comment: Any suggest?   Error 2 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'InvokeRequired' and no extension method 'InvokeRequired' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably took that code from Windows Forms, where every Control has a `Invoke` method. In WPF you need to use the [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615907.aspx) object, accessible through a [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject.dispatcher.aspx) property:

```
 if (control.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
 {
     control.Text = text;
 }
 else
 {
     SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
     control.Dispatcher.Invoke(d, new object[] { control, text });
 }
```

Additionally, you're not calling `SetText` correctly. It takes two arguments, which in C# are separated with commas, not with equal signs:

```
SetText(currentIterationBox.Text, iteration.ToString());
```

Comment: it is still gets an error when I call it like this "SetText(currentIterationBox.Text = iteration.ToString());"

Comment: @Reza: **WHAT ERROR?** Why do you think they write the error descriptions? Because it's fun? Did you even read it? I bet it explains what's wrong.

Comment: sorry, here's the error "Error 2 No overload for method 'SetText' takes 1 argument"

Answer (score 6):

In WPF you dont use Control.Invoke but Dispatcher.Invoke like this:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate(){
  // your code
});
```

Use

```
Dispatcher.CheckAccess()
```

to check first.

Comment: i edit my code above, is it correct? because it's still get error when I call it like this SetText(currentIterationBox.Text = iteration.ToString());

Comment: SetText is a method with two parameters, one is a texbox the other is a string. You should call it like this: SetText(currentIterationBox,  iteration.ToString());

Answer (score 3):

In WPF using next construction:

```
if (control.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
{
   ...
}
else
{
   control.Dispatcher.Invoke(...)
}
```